How to produce a very fast https empty reply from nginx?
I have an nginx balancer and after two application servers with apache and tomcat.
I need to create a very fast https response server to let the client monitor the speed of its connection measuring the latency of a Get http Ajax call.
So my goal is to create the fastest ever http reply from nginx balancer. Don't mind the content of the response, it can be empty. It is just to let the client understand how long does it take a ping/pong call.
What do you think is the best way? Of course I already excluded a simple script and an empty file for its overhead.

If you use https most of the latency will be in the SSL handshake before Nginx receives anything.

What specifically are you trying to measure?  If you want to measure the network latency between the server and client, you'll want to establish that TLS over TCP connection first.  Actually, you'll probably want to skip using HTTP altogether.  Consider a UDP connection with an unreliable WebRTC data channel so that you don't have to worry about transparent proxies, unexpected compression layers, etc.

I just need to give a feedback to user about his current connection, just to understand if will be safe or not to keep working with my web application. Then I want to create a "signal level" icon to control using a scheduled ping/pong timer. This is the reason why I want the fastest answer from my webserver, because it is not importat the response, but just its timing. I can consider to use http instead of https but I'm a bit worried because the app is https and probably the browser will complain about the safetly of an ajax call to an http-non-s page.
